# how to add physcs to a animated sprite

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing a game in android with andengine. I use both animated sprite and sprite.When i set dynamic property to the animated sprite body, it crashes. But it works fine with static.

How to add gravity to the animated sprite

Here is my code

```
sprCat = new AnimatedSprite(0, 0, regCat, engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    catBody=PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(physicsWorld, sprCat, BodyType.DynamicBody, wallFixtureDef);
    catBody.setUserData("cat");
    gameScene.this.attachChild(sprCat);
    physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(sprCat, catBody, true, true));


    sprCat.animate(100);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have done this successfully but creating the connector within the update thread, something like this:

```
final AnimatedSprite mExplosion1 = new AnimatedSprite(100,100,mTiledRegionExplosion,getVertexBufferObjectManager());
mScene.attachChild(mExplosion1);

mEngine.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(mExplosion1, mBoxBody, true, true));
    }
});     
mExplosion1.animate(60,false);
```

mBoxBody is dynamic body, created previously.